# Why do I have higher noise at far end of a DC power cable even when unplugged at that end?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, noise, emc, shielding

I have a 750W DCDC converter that is putting out 24v. The converter has a stated ripple max of around 600mV and when measured directly at the output (scope lead tip pin the the output, lead ground ring directly on the ground at the output), it is well within spec.

But when measured at the far end of the cable (about 2 meters), the ripple noise is around ten times that value. It’s this way whether the cable is plugged into the load or not.

Output goes through blade fuse to cable (there are no additional ferrites on the output but there are external caps). Cable is unshielded.

The only thing I can think of is that it’s picking up radiated noise from the DCDC itself, but it seems like a huge amount.  Any other thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: What is the model of the converter? Often ripple is specified at max. load condition. In no-load situation the ripple could well be different. The caps sit directly at the output, before the fuse? How much capacitance?

Comment: Likely a measurement setup problem. But we don't know how exactly you have connected the wires between scope and PSU, and how they are connectes to mains, is the converter PSU output floating or referenced to earth at the PSU, etc. With 2 meter leads, you are not just measuring the PSU itself any more. And manufacturers say under which conditions the ripple is measured. Usually this includes input voltage, output current, some lead length, some capacitors right at the probe with specific probing technique, probe settings and bandwidth, and scope bandwidth.

Comment: Ripple is specified as max for load or no load. Capacitance is one 1000uF, 2xMLCC 22uF, all as per the application note / data sheet.

Comment: I measured using the tip and barrel technique as shown in figure 7 here. It’s a dcdc so Justme, do you want to know how the scope is grounded?  It’s just plugged into the wall. Scope leads are normal and don’t change between measuring at the DCDC output and end of cable. Measurement matches exactly what they specify at the converter, it’s just much larger at the end of the cables the converter connects to (I.e. the load). https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/industry-articles/switching-regulator-output-artifacts-expedites-power-supply-design/

Comment: Draw a precise schematic of the measurement set-up. Why not measure at the power supply end before and after connecting the cable? Images of the waveforms are nearly mandatory.